# in whm where can i access(type) "/scripts/installimagemagick"

Tags: php, apache, centos, php-extension, whm

my server is on whm and trying to install imagemagick and then imagick, but can't seem to find out where to type in:

```
/scripts/installimagemagick
```

I currently do not have commandline access to do this.  So how else can i go about installing imagemagick and imagick?  I checked phpinfo(), and both do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Without SSH access you can not install installimagemagick on your cPanel server through WHM. You need SSH access to install installimagemagick and imagick php modules on your server.

Check if the package is already installed

```
[root@24x7~]# rpm -qa |grep -i magick

[root@24x7~]# /scripts/installimagemagick
```

Add php module "imagick"

```
[root@24x7~]# pecl install imagick
```

Check php imagick module

```
[root@24x7~]#php -m | grep imagick
imagick
```

Answer (score 0):

The script to automatically install ImageMagick was removed as of version 58.0.25:

Fixed case CPANEL-8229: Remove scripts/installimagemagick for 11.58.

**EA-PHP Extension via SSH or Terminal:**

First, remove any old RPM installs:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i Magick
rpm -e "here enter anything that pops up"
```

Then Install the Required Packages
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel

Sometimes the command will generate an error, so another package must be installed as a prerequisite:

```
yum install pcre-devel
```

If a domain uses php 7.1 for example, run the following command:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/pecl install imagick
```

You can customize this command based on the required php version:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-phpXX/root/usr/bin/pecl install imagick
```